# Reference Java interface static fields in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Can I reference Java interface fields from Kotlin? I have this Java interface:

```
public interface BaseColumns {
    public static final String _ID = "_id";
    public static final String _COUNT = "_count";
}
```

And I implement it in Kotlin:

```
object UserEntry : BaseColumns {
    // some code
}
```

I get **Unresolved reference** when I try `UserEntry._ID`. How can I access the `_ID`? Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Kotlin, unlike Java, static members of interfaces are not derived and cannot be called in subclasses without qualifying the interface name.

You should reference `_ID` through `BaseColumns`: `BaseColumns._ID` will work.

This seems to be different for classes: non-qualified name of a base class static member resolves to it, but the member is still not inherited.

Comment: Follow up question: in this particular case there then is no reason to implement the BaseColumns interface right? As it only contains two static member variables?