# How do I access a Java static method on a Kotlin subclass?

Tags: kotlin

I've created a Kotlin subclass of a Java class:

```
class AlarmReceiver : WakefulBroadcastReceiver() {

    companion object {
        const val ACTION_NOTIFY = "..."
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) { ... }
}
```

[`WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) has two static methods:

- `static boolean completeWakefulIntent(Intent intent)`
- `static ComponentName startWakefulService(Context context, Intent intent)`

and calling these from within my `AlarmReceiver` class works just as I expect. However, I'd like to call one of these methods *outside of my Kotlin subclass*.

### The Problem

If I try `AlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent)` from a different Kotlin class, I get the following compilation error:

> Unresolved reference: completeWakefulIntent

I think this is because the compiler is trying to resolve the method on `AlarmReceiver`'s companion object instead of finding the inherited method from its superclass. As a workaround, I can directly define a method with the same signature on `AlarmReceiver.Companion`:

```
class AlarmReceiver : WakefulBroadcastReceiver() {

    companion object {
        const val ACTION_NOTIFY = "..."

        // Just call the superclass implementation for now
        fun completeWakefulIntent(intent: Intent): Boolean =
            WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent)
    }

    ...
}
```

I think this has the same behavior I would have gotten had I relied on the default inherited method from a Java subclass, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Is there a way to call an inherited static Java method on a Kotlin subclass?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Kotlin, unlike Java, static members are not inherited by subclasses, even though they can be called inside a subclass without the base class name.

Outside a subclass, you have to call the base class static functions using the base class name:

```
WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent)
```

This behavior seems to lie within the companion objects concept: companion objects of classes in a hierarchy are not included into each other.

<sub>Interestingly, for interfaces the situation is a bit different: [interface static members cannot be referenced in subclasses without the interface name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297980/reference-java-interface-static-fields-in-kotlin/35298665#35298665). This behavior is [the same to that in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169175/why-are-class-static-methods-inherited-but-not-interface-static-methods).</sub>

Comment: Ah, that would explain it. Do you happen to know where it's documented that static members are not inherited?

Comment: Nope, I haven't come across any mention of it in the docs. The most *official* explanation seems to be [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/3oj1xm/how_to_refer_to_super_static_fields_in_kotlin_code/cvxxtan?st=isc2avuz&sh=0f63921a) given by @yole.

Comment: Thanks! I also didn't see anything in the docs and probably wouldn't have found this on my own.